# I want to sum up certain values in an array of objects with Reduce

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to sum up only the pro and elite players using the Reduce method.

```
data = [ 
  { name: 'pro', players: 3 },
  { name: 'free', players: 8 },
  { name: 'elite', players: 1 } 
  ]
```

I know Reduce returns the total number of players of 12 but I only want to return the sum of pro and elite players.

My reduce method so far.

```
const players = data.reduce((accum, cur) => {
   return accum + cur.players;
}, 0);
```

This returns 12.

However, I want it to only return 4 by only adding the pro and elite players.

Comment: So what's the problem? In your callback function, test the value of `tierName`, and add to the accumulator if it matches your criteria.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yea, I tried doing what ajhaining did below with an if statement and I realized I put the return statement in the wrong place. haha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an if statement into the function you pass to the reduce method, that will only add to the accumulator if a condition is met, else just return the accumulator...

```
const players = data.reduce((accum, cur) => {
    if (cur.name === "pro" || cur.name === "elite") {
        return accum + cur.players;
    }
    return accum;
}, 0);
```

Or you could filter the list and then reduce it...

```
const players = data
    .filter(item => item.name === "pro" || item.name === "elite")
    .reduce((accum, cur) => accum + cur.players, 0);
```

The docs for both the [reduce method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and the [filter method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) are great.

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cugjzrnb/) showing both options. (Open developer console to see output)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way with destructuring.

```
const totalPaidPlayers = data.filter(({ name }) => name !== 'free')
.reduce((total, { players }) => (total + players), 0)
```

Or like this.  Same exact way but with return after the arrow functions.

```
  const totalPaidPlayers = data.filter(({ name }) => {
    return name !== 'free'
  }).reduce((total, {players}) => {
    return total + players
  }, 0)
```